# javascript regex to find only numbers with hyphen from a string content

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript, from a string like this, I am trying to extract only the number with a hyphen. i.e. 67-64-1 and 35554-44-04. Sometimes there could be more hyphens.

> The solvent 67-64-1 is not compatible with 35554-44-04

I tried different regex but not able to get it correctly. For example, this regex gets only the first value.

```js
var msg = 'The solvent 67-64-1 is not compatible with 35554-44-04';
//var regex = /\d+\-?/;
var regex = /(?:\d*-\d*-\d*)/;
var res = msg.match(regex);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Try using `\b\d+(?:-\d+)+\b` https://regex101.com/r/6pAvyu/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the `g` (global) flag to your regex to match more than once in the string. Note that you should use `\d+`, not `\d*`, so that you don't match something like '3--4'. To allow for processing numbers with more hyphens, we use a repeating `-\d+` group after the first `\d+`:

```js
var msg = 'The solvent 67-64-1 is not compatible with 23-35554-44-04 but is compatible with 1-23';
var regex = /\d+(?:-\d+)+/g;
var res = msg.match(regex);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks, how to make it to also consider numbers with more hyphens eg. 35554-44-23-213

Comment: @Jay What should it do with a value like `f35554-44-23-213g`?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thanks it should ignore. Its actually chemical CAS numbers made out of only numbers with hyphen separators.

Comment: @Jay is it actually likely you'll see a string like that?

Answer (score 1):

It gives only first because regex work for first element to test

```
// g give globel access to find all
var regex = /(?:\d*-\d*-\d*)/g;
```